# Deploy pre-trained tensorflow model on the aws sagemaker - ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation

Tags: amazon-web-services, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving, amazon-sagemaker

This is the first time I am using amazon web services to deploy my machine learning pre-trained model. I want to deploy my pre-trained TensorFlow model to Aws-Sagemaker. I am somehow able to deploy the endpoints successfully But whenever I call the `predictor.predict(some_data)` method to make prediction to invoking the endpoints it's throwing an error.

```
ModelError: An error occurred (ModelError) when calling the InvokeEndpoint operation: Received server error (500) from model with message "". See https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-west-2#logEventViewer:group=/aws/sagemaker/Endpoints/sagemaker-tensorflow-2020-04-07-04-25-27-055 in account 453101909370 for more information.
```

After going through the cloud watch logs I found this error.

```
#011details = "NodeDef mentions attr 'explicit_paddings' not in Op<name=Conv2D; signature=input:T, filter:T -> output:T; attr=T:type,allowed=[DT_HALF, DT_BFLOAT16, DT_FLOAT, DT_DOUBLE]; attr=strides:list(int); attr=use_cudnn_on_gpu:bool,default=true; attr=padding:string,allowed=["SAME", "VALID"]; attr=data_format:string,default="NHWC",allowed=["NHWC", "NCHW"]; attr=dilations:list(int),default=[1, 1, 1, 1]>; NodeDef: {{node conv1_conv/convolution}} = Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, _output_shapes=[[?,112,112,64]], data_format="NHWC", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], explicit_paddings=[], padding="VALID", strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](conv1_pad/Pad, conv1_conv/kernel/read). (Check whether your GraphDef-interpreting binary is up to date with your GraphDef-generating binary.).
```

I don't know where I am wrong and I have wasted 2 days already to solve this error and couldn't find out the information regarding this. The detailed logs I have shared [here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1NXsLRd6cfbNE55xSVq5d63ETt-cBmwZsOaic8IyF1Qw/edit?usp=sharing).

Tensorflow version of my notebook instance is 1.15

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching and try & error, I was able to solve this problem. In many cases, the problem arises because of the TensorFlow and Python versions.

**Cause of the problem:**
To deploy the endpoints, I was using the `TensorflowModel` on TF 1.12 and python 3 and which exactly caused the problem.

> ```
> sagemaker_model = TensorFlowModel(model_data = model_data,
>                                   role = role,
>                                   framework_version = '1.12',
>                                   entry_point = 'train.py')
> ```

Apparently, `TensorFlowModel` only allows python 2 on TF version 1.11, 1.12. 2.1.0.

**How I fixed it:** There are two TensorFlow solutions that handle serving in the Python SDK. They have different class representations and documentation as shown here.

1. **TensorFlowModel** - https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/model.py#L47

- Doc:
  https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/tree/v1.12.0/src/sagemaker/tensorflow#deploying-directly-from-model-artifacts
- Key difference: Uses a proxy GRPC client to send requests
- Container impl:
  https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/blob/master/src/tf_container/serve.py

2. **Model** - https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/serving.py#L96

- Doc: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-python-sdk/blob/master/src/sagemaker/tensorflow/deploying_tensorflow_serving.rst
- Key difference: Utilizes the TensorFlow serving rest API
- Container impl: https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-serving-container/blob/master/container/sagemaker/serve.py

Python 3 isn't supported using the `TensorFlowModel` object, as the container uses the TensorFlow serving API library in conjunction with the GRPC client to handle making inferences, however, the TensorFlow serving API isn't supported in Python 3 officially, so there are only Python 2 versions of the containers when using the `TensorFlowModel` object.
If you need Python 3 then you will need to use the `Model` object defined in #2 above.

Finally, I used the `Model` with the TensorFlow version 1.15.1.

> ```
> sagemaker_model = Model(model_data = model_data,
>                         role = role,
>                         framework_version='1.15.2',
>                         entry_point = 'train.py')
> ```

Also, here are the successful results.
[image]